# What values will return 0 in this function?

Tags: javascript

The following function uses a [Short Circuit Operator](http://www.openjs.com/articles/syntax/short_circuit_operators.php) to return `0` as default:

```
function custNumParse(str){
    return str*1||0;
}
```

I am not sure when this will return the second (I mean, I know that it will when `str*1` can't be evaluated to `true`), but I am not sure what inputs could produce that output when multiplying by `1`.

I know that the falsish values are `0, "", false, null, undefined, NaN`, but this doesn't help me that much.

In other words I am clueless what would happen when I use that function with objects or booleans, etc. I know I can test them all, but I am sure there is an easier way to go

Any ideas on what is the most proper way to find these guys without testing them all?

Comment: `str+1` could also be written as `+str`.

Comment: @Rocket what `+1`? you meant `*1`?

Comment: Yeah I meant `str*1`, that was a typo.  Anyway, you could still write `+str`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` operator is only for numbers, so anything that's not a number (or can't be converted to one) will make `str*1` return `NaN`.  Also `0*1` is obviously `0`.

EDIT: booleans seems to be converted to either `0` or `1`.

```
false * 1 === 0
true * 1 === 1
```

EDIT 2: Strings with numeric values will also be converted

```
"12" * 1 === 12
"0" * 1 === 0
```

EDIT 3: Be careful with arrays (they are converted to strings and then to ints).

```
[] * 1 === 0
[2] * 1 === 2
[1,2] * 1 === NaN
```

Comment: what about booleans or strings using numbers? edit because your `(or can't be converted to one)` edit. Oh I see... well that shorten the tests a lot, thanks :D

Comment: Not true.  `[]*1` returns `0`.  So his question still stands, how are other types cast to numbers.  For example `true*1` is `1`.

Comment: I was slightly wrong.  Values will be converted to a number (if they can) before the `*` operation.

Comment: @DMoses: That's because `[]` is converted to `""` which is converted to `0`.

Comment: @Rocket +1 good point about how the conversion is taking place.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is typecasting.  The value str will be typecast and then multiplied.  See these examples from http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=819

```
Number(false) 0
Number(true) 1
Number(undefined) NaN
Number(null) 0
Number("5.5") 5.5
Number("56") 56
Number("5.6.7") NaN
Number(new Object()) NaN
Number(100) 10
```

So `"5.5"*1` is true.

Comment: that link is very useful, I am impressed on how much time it will save me sooner or later

Comment: Note that the link talks of **explicit** typecasting in javascript.  Your current code was **implicitly** typecasting.

Comment: thanks for the warning, I will combine your link with the ans of 'Rocket' to easily know who will turn to `NaN` :)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is weakly typed. This means when you multiply something by 1, it will try to change that thing into a number first.

- If you have a string that looks like a number, it will try to interpret it. Since multiplying by 1 doesn't do anything to a number, you will get that number back.
- If the string doesn't look like a number, the expression will fail and result in `NaN`. Since `NaN` is false, it will fall through and return `0` instead.
- There's no logical way to make an object into a number either, so you'll end up with `NaN` as well.
- As for booleans, true is 1 and false is 0.

So what the function does is it tries to interpret the argument as a number, and failing that, returns 0.